# How to fix the foreign key references form an incorrect parent record to another record when both already exist? (PostgreSQL 14)

Tags: postgresql, merge, constraints

PostgreSQL 14

Summary: The following schema has multiple text strings (specialty, doctorname, officename) which can be misspelled.

The challenge: How to correctly change the foreign keys from an **existing** misspelled record to another (correctly spelled) **existing** record. Unique constraints are in play and there are multiple child tables.

I have the following table layout:

```
CREATE TABLE specialties
(
    specialtyid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    specialty text not null unique check (specialty <> '')
);

CREATE TABLE Doctors
(
    doctorid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    doctorname text not null UNIQUE CHECK (doctorname <> ''), 
    specialtyid integer not null, 
    CONSTRAINT doctors_specialty_fk FOREIGN KEY (specialtyid)
        REFERENCES specialties (specialtyid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE Offices
(
    officeid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    officename text not null CHECK (officename <> '') UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE staff
(
    staffid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    officeid integer not null,
    doctorid integer not null,
    CONSTRAINT staff_unique UNIQUE(officeid,doctorid),
    CONSTRAINT staff_office_fk FOREIGN KEY (officeid)
        REFERENCES offices (officeid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT staff_doctor_fk FOREIGN KEY (doctorid)
        REFERENCES doctors (doctorid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE Referrals
(
    referralid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    officeid integer,
    doctorid integer,
    specialtyid integer,
    CONSTRAINT referrals_office_fk FOREIGN KEY (officeid)
        REFERENCES offices (officeid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT referrals_doctor_fk FOREIGN KEY (doctorid)
        REFERENCES doctors (doctorid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT referrals_specialty_fk FOREIGN KEY (specialtyid)
        REFERENCES specialties (specialtyid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE orders
(
    orderid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    encounterid integer NOT NULL,
    referralid integer,
    CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
    CONSTRAINT referral_unique UNIQUE (encounterid, referralid), 
    CONSTRAINT orders_referral_fk FOREIGN KEY (referralid)
        REFERENCES referrals (referralid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE RESTRICT
        ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

The orders table has been greatly simplified.

As can be seen, the general idea is that each specialty can have multiple doctors and a doctor can be in one or more offices. An order for a referral
will reference a referral record that could be either to an office, doctor, or specialty.

What I can't quit get is how to manage a misspelled string for doctor, specialty, or office. That is, assume their are two records in specialty
where the first has "Noorosurgery" and the second has "Neurosurgery". Each of these records is linked down through the system with
appropropriate doctors, staff records, offices, referrals, and orders.

Now at some later date, the misspelled word is corrected to "Neurosurgery". This throw an immediate error (as it should) that Neurosurgery is
no longer unique. This, ofcourse, can be deferred until the situation is fixed, but how can the correct record reference be sent down
through the tree such that all the links with all the children be correctly changed? Additionally, can this be automated such that if more child tables are added, no further changes would be needed?

@ErwinBrandstetter ["Merge" two rows in a Postgres table, with foreign keys](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122306/merge-two-rows-in-a-postgres-table-with-foreign-keys)
comes close, but is not the same problem.

In my previous attempts, I essentially created a maze of temporary tables within a transaction and set the constraints to deferred.  I an new to PostgreSQL 14 and hope there is a better way. (I was using PostgreSQL 9).

There must be a better way.

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a single query; abet with multiple steps.  First create a CTE that retrieves the `specialtyid` for both the incorrect and the correct spelled `specialties`. Now since Postgres allows for DML operation in a CTE you create a CTE for each table. Finally, delete rows the incorrect spelling.  (see [domo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/H7PviG8e), you did not provide data so I just generated some).

```
--  Apply corrections 
with corrections(old_spec, new_spec) as 
     ( select o.specialtyid, n.specialtyid 
         from specialties o
         join specialties n
           on (o.specialty = 'Noorosurgery' and n.specialty = 'Neurosurgery')
           or (o.specialty = 'Opthalmology' and n.specialty = 'Ophthalmology')
      )
   ,  do_doc as 
       ( update doctors 
            set specialtyid = new_spec
           from corrections
          where specialtyid = old_spec
          --returning new_spec
       ) 
   , do_ref as
       ( update referrals
            set specialtyid = new_spec
           from corrections
          where specialtyid = old_spec
          --returning new_spec
       )
delete from specialties
 where specialtyid in (select old_spec 
                         from corrections
                       );
```

NOTE: Tables `offices1,` staff`,` orders` are not necessary for solution.

Comment: Thanks. Can I correctly assume that the CTE's are being  run in the order given even though not directly called in the final delete clause?

Comment: I would not make that assumption. As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) Section 7.8.4. Data-Modifying Statements in WITH *The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable.*